# Converting strings to integers from an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, token, parseint

I'm trying to convert some strings from an array to integers using parseInt().  I am reading in lines from many separate files which look like this:

```
car,house,548544587,645871266
```

I have something like the code below:

```
String [] tokens = line.split(",");
try {
        line = line.trim();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
        int c = (b - a);
        System.out.println(c);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
            }
```

But this fails with errors like this, for each line I read in:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "548544587"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "645871266"
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the quotes before splitting. It fails to convert `"number"` to an actual number because of quotes.

```
String line = "\"car\",\"house\",\"548544587\",\"645871266\"";
String[] tokens = line.replace("\"", "").split(",");
try {

    int a = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
    int c = (b - a);
    System.out.println(c);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

**Output:**

```
97326679
```

Comment: Sorry, I had the line example wrong that I read in.  It actually doesn't include quotes anywhere.  I've updated my original post to show this.  (Which is why this is stumping me...)

Comment: @gppanter i think it's an major update.. did you try this `String [] tokens = line.trim().split(",");` ?

Comment: @gppanter why you failed to ask about this on very first?

Comment: I did try that as well but get the same exceptions thrown.  Trimming first doesn't seem to help.

Comment: trim after splitting `int a = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].trim());`

Comment: Thought that would work too, but it didn't.  It must be something to do with the files I am reading from, though there really isn't much to them.  Just a single line in each one, like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `String` for `line` does not produce an error for me, so it must be tied to what you're reading from the file. Also of note, you trim the line, but not each element in `tokens`. Try trimming each element, e.g., `int a = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].trim());`. Also, you might be getting carriage return characters like `\n` and/or `\r`, so try to replace those before the split, e.g., `String[] tokens = line.replaceAll("\\n", "").replaceAll("\\r", "").split(",");`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't help either...I thought it would!  Interestingly though, if I changed my lines to use 'floats' instead, it worked, insofar as it returned an integer.

Comment: That is very interesting. What I would do next is check each character in the token, which might lead you to the error. 
         `char[] aa = tokens[2].trim().toCharArray();
            for(char c : aa) { 
                System.out.print(c + " ");
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(""+c)); 
            }`
, but that's just what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String line="car,house,548544587,645871266";
        String [] tokens = line.split(",");
        try {
                line = line.trim();             
                int a = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].trim());
                int b = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].trim());
                System.out.println(a+ " "+b);
                int c = (b - a);
                System.out.println(c);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                    }

    }
    Output;
    548544587 645871266
    97326679
```